# Why does my axios request print in console but doesn't set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to display some data from my database in my React component but the data isn't getting saved in the state hook, but the request's response does print in the console.

How can I fix this?

```
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [collections, setCollections] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getCollections = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/collections');
      setIsLoaded(true);

      console.log(response); // This prints the response
      setCollections(response);
      console.log(collections); // This prints []

    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
      setIsLoaded(true);
    }
  }

  getCollections();
}, [])
```

[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWgVT.png)

Comment: ```await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/collections').then((response)=>setCollections(response))```
try this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setCollections` is not executed immediately by React. The new state should be available on the next render. Try logging during the render phase:

```
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [collections, setCollections] = useState([]);

console.log(collections);

useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see indeed that in the next render I can get the data. How would you wait with mapping the data until it is in the next render? Can you do that with {collections && rendering of the collections}?

Comment: Yes, you can. More precisely, something like `collections.length > 1 && render...`